# What is the purpose of Jane Street Base's *_intf.ml files?

Tags: module, ocaml

This is a general OCaml question.

A .mli file usually provides the "interface" for its corresponding .ml file.

But in Jane Street's Base sometimes there are three files with the same name-minus-extension, for example ([commit](https://github.com/janestreet/base/tree/914648d/src)):

- binary_searchable.ml
- binary_searchable.mli
- binary_searchable_intf.ml

Why do only some `.ml`s have corresponding `.ml_intf.ml` files? And, more generally, what are the limitations of the `.mli` format such that `_intf.ml` files are sometimes needed?

Answer (score 4):

This is explained in detail in this [article on "the _intf trick"](https://www.craigfe.io/posts/the-intf-trick/), but in short, as I understand it, it's to avoid having to repeat large type definitions, especially module types, in both the interface and implementation files.

Essentially, if you have a large type definition that is not intended to be abstracted away externally, say:

```
type t =
  | A of int
  | B of string
  ...
  | Z of (int array, string * float)
```

Instead of duplicating this definition in both `Foo.ml` and `Foo.mli`, you can put it in `Foo_intf.ml`, and then in the `.ml` and `.mli` file simply write:

```
include Foo_intf
```

Comment: For people finding this answer: duplicating large definitions can also be avoided with https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ppx_import. I haven't tried it yet